# How to obtain two builds of the same version of boost library with Homebrew?

Tags: c++, boost, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I would like to have two parallel builds of the same boost library (on OSX Yosemite): one which is compiled using clang with libc++ linkage and another compiled using gcc with libstdc++ linkage. I would basically want two kegs:

1. Cellar/boost/1_56_0_libc++/
2. Cellar/boost/1_56_0_libstdc++/

The former build is needed for python-based programs, the latter build is needed for my Linux-based development which rely on libstdc++. I guess it would be fairly easy to relink these libraries to /usr/local/ as needed. For example if 1) is linked, but I want to do Linux-type development, I could switch using something like: `brew unlink boost_1_56_0 && brew link boost_1_56_0_libstdc++`.

I know how to build 1) or 2), but I don't know how to have both. So my question in:

How is it possible to install/link/maintain two kegs like these?

Any comment or answer is much appreciated.

Comment: How about simply copying the boost formula and changing the paths?

Comment: 1) I copy-pasted boost.rb: `cp boost.rb boost_gcc.rb` 
2) Then renamed the class in `boost_gcc.rb` to `Boost_gcc` 
3) And ran brew: `sudo brew install boost_gcc -v`
4) An error came up: `Error: uninitialized constant BoostGcc`

Comment: I tried the same but didn't use an underscore in the formula(boost-gcc) and I first created the formula with `brew create myboost` and then copied the contents. `brew info myboost` worked then.

Comment: Thanks @bamboon, the formula seems to work, it's compiling now...